# Windows 8 Home - Change network profile

Tags: networking, windows-8, home-networking, network-profiles

I searched high and low for this.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change a customer's network profile from public to private.
The laptop is connected to the enterprise network and I don't know anything about it's configuration.

What can I do / should I ask them to do in order to be able to change the profile?

I used [this tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9837-network-location-set-private-public-windows-8-a.html) to try and change it, but neither of them worked because some exe's aren't available in Win 8 home. The registry tweak did change the name displayed in network and charing center but didn't flip over the connected network profile (sharing settings).

Even when I go to the folder network locations, a yellow bar on the top appears telling me that sharing is disabled. When I go ahead and click that a popup informs me that I need to change the profile to private. When I choose to change the network profile there, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all other approaches failed.  You can delete the network profile which will require the user to supply the authentication information again but it will allow you to switch the network location to Private.

1. Press the [image] + R keys to open the Run dialog, type regedit, and press Enter.
2. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on **Yes**
3. In Registry Editor, navigate to the location below. (see screenshot below)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles

[image]

4. Double click/tap on the Profiles key in the left pane to expand it. Click/tap on each long GUID number subkey, and look at it's PofileName string value in the right pane to see if it has the current network name (ex: Network) until found. (see screenshots below)

[image]
[image]

5. When you find the correct **ProfileName** for your network, while its highlight, press the **Delete** key while the entry for the entire profile for example `{84464353-7131-4F3B-B4BD-28C7DE44DE00}`, is highlighted.

[Source](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9837-network-location-set-private-public-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: I'll try this monday, thanks.
You mentioned that I could change the profile to public... you mean private, right? It's public I want to get rid of ;)

Comment: @RobbieVercammen - I will make an update to reflect that fact.